# VBA not specific user name when exporting PDF

Tags: vba, authentication, pdf, save

I have a working code below opening and saving a PDF file for 1 specific user to documents folder.
The issue I do not know is how to replace specific user name like SmithJoe with any other user. The code should be used by more users. Now it doesn´t work when for example TaylorRog tries to use the code. It is working for SmithJoe only.
Is there any possibility to replace specific user "SmithJoe" with all users?

`Sheets("ABC").Range("G8:j18").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _ "C:\Users\SmithJoe\Documents\fileA.pdf", Quality:= _ xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _ OpenAfterPublish:=True`

Thank you in advance

Comment: `Environ("USERPROFILE")`.

Answer (score 1):

To get the content of an Windows environment variable, use the function `Environ`.
To get the username, use `Environ("USERNAME")`.

But note that there are cases where the name of the folder is not equal to the name of the user or the location of the folder is different from `C:\Users`. It's better to use `Environ("USERPROFILE")` - in your case that should return `C:\Users\SmithJoe`.

But of course that's not the full story. The documents-folder could have a different name or it could be in a different place. To be on the save side, you need to query the folder. There are several ways to do so, I found the following method the easiest:

```
Function GetSystemFolder(folderID) As String
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim f
    Set f = CreateObject("Shell.Application").namespace(folderID)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If Not f Is Nothing Then GetSystemFolder2 = f.Self.path
End Function
```

The parameter `folderID` tells the function which folder you want, the document folder has the value 5. A list of all ids can be found [at Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shldisp/ne-shldisp-shellspecialfolderconstants).

You code could look like this

```
Const ssfPERSONAL = &H5
...
Dim pdfFilename as String
pdfFilename = GetSystemFolder(ssfPERSONAL) & "\fileA.pdf"

Sheets("ABC").Range("G8:j18").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, 
       Filename:= pdfFilename , Quality:= xlQualityStandard, _
       IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _ 
       OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot.

May I have another question? To make the code work, I need to:

1. create this function:

   Function GetSystemFolder(folderID) As String
2. create the Sub macro with the code

   Const ssfPERSONAL = &H5
   ...
   Dim pdfFilename as String
   pdfFilename = GetSystemFolder(ssfPERSONAL) & "\fileA.pdf" etc.

What content should be instead of the three dots? `Const ssfPERSONAL = &H5 ... Dim pdfFilename as String`

I am trying to solve it myself but did not succeed.
Thank you.

Comment: You shoudn't post another question as an answer. SO is not a forum and has no threads. You ask *one* question (you did so), which is answered (hopefully). Good answers are upvoted, really bad are downvoted, the answer that fit best should be accepted by you. If you have a new question (even if it is a follow-up), raise a new question.